# Lower bound on variance of sum of random variables

Tags: probability

Let $X,Y$ be two positive random variables. Is it true that $Var(X+Y) \geq \dfrac{Var(X)+Var(Y)}{2}$.

Comment: Suppose $X=1+\epsilon$ and $Y=1-\epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ is a small random variable.

Comment: In the first line of your proof attempt, there should be a factor of $2$ in front of the covariance. Then, the resulting work gives $Var(X+Y) \ge 0$.

Comment: You miss the factor $2$ before covariance, and thus you will obtain $Var[X+Y] \geq 0$ in the last line as expected, which is trivial. Have you read about lulu's comment? This trivial lower bound is attained when you are talking about the variance of a constant/degenerated random variable. So when $X+Y$ is a constant, then it attains the lower bound, which cannot be improved unless you have more assumptions to exclude this trivial example.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I am sorry, i missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered:

As noted in the comments, you missed a factor of $2$, and the claim is in fact false, since $X+Y$ can be a constant with zero variance with $X$ and $Y$ non-constant with non-zero variance.